# How do I export an animated scene with a rigged character and dds textures to blender from 3DSMAX 7?

Tags: blender, 3dsmax

Which format should I use, which settings? Which plugin or script?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried already, give us something to work from.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started.

http://www.katsbits.com/tools/